# GeoServer 2.11.2 print with MapFish

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish

I'm beginner with GeoServer.

I have a jsf page in my application website (`   PDF Export ).

I want to export the map in PDF.

I added the print module to the GeoServer application.

Then I created the jasper report, 
but I do not know where I'm going to create and put the config.yaml file and the spec param...

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html#verifying-installation) the config file goes in `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/printing/config.yaml`